# Animated flight/drive path on map

Tags: animation

Is there a software that can create an animation of a flight/drive path by entering two cities?
I don't want to use the tour function in google earth because I would like to see just the path being drawn from point A to B similar to the animated map function in imovie.
In google earth for example I can't do that and manually recording a tour is very tedious. Any ideas? I need this to be used in a slideshow of pictures, so I want to show first the flight path on a map and then pictures.

Comment: I remember doing that once, I'm not sure if it was all possible in Google Earth's interface. You can do it by editing the .kml file, see [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9344496/1781026).

Comment: @chrki wow that looks like more work than I am willing to do. I am looking for something quick.